# Groovy method returning null

Tags: groovy

So i have a class "TestClass"

```
class TestClass {
    public abstract class Test {
        private String _string

        public Test(String string) {
            _string = string
         }

        private TreeSet<List<String>> _rows = new TreeSet<List<String>>()
        public Collection<List<String>> getRows() {
            return _rows
        }
        public abstract void processObject(XmlObject object) 
    }
    private List<Test> list = [ 
         new getData() //long list of classes
    ]

    //this method is supposed to to through the list and return "_rows" which doesnt seem to work
    public List<Test> returnRows() {
        list.each { Test test ->
            return test.getRows()
        }
    }
    public getData extends Test {
        public getData() {
            super('test')
        }
        @Override
        public void processObject(XmlObject object) {
            getRows().add(['test'])
        }
    }
    public TestClass() {
        //constructor
    }
}
```

I am calling TestClass in another file here:

```
class AnotherClass {
    public void run() {
        def testClass
        testClass = getClass().classLoader.parseClass(new File(classpath)).newInstance()
        testClass.returnRows().each { //it is failing here saying that testClass.returnRows() is null
    }
}
```

but testClass.returnRows() is null

I am not sure if the method returnRows() is not returning anything or if I am not instantiating the class correctly

Comment: It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger. Please help yourself to some complementary debugging techniques.

Comment: The first problem is that you should be caling `list.each { ... }` rather than `list.each() { ... }`.

Comment: `each() {}` is overly verbose, but no problem

Comment: `each` is for sideeffects only and returns the incoming list.  So what you want around your comment there is most likely `collect` or `collectMany`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code `returnRows()` never return any data that's why you getting `null`.

Rewrite method `returnsRows()` code as follow:

```
    public List<Test> returnRows() {
        def returnListVariable=[]
        list.each { Test test ->
            //test.getRows()
           returnListVariable << test.getRows()
        }
        return returnListVariable
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Method `each` is a void method which not returns any data.
In your case, when you call `each` method, you pass a anonymous function to it and apply a return to exit this function.

Use method `collect` instead, which must return collected elements list.

```
public List<Test> returnRows() {
    return list.collect({ Test test ->
        return test.getRows()
    })
}
```